# Display one record per page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have 2 objects with a lookup relationship. Let say account and contact.

I want to display one account with related contacts per page. One click of next, will display the next account and contacts. How can I achieve this without pagination?

Answer (score 2):

```
                  <apex:commandLink action="{!navigate}" value="{!h.name}">
                        <apex:param name="qno" value="{!h.Id}"
                            assignTo="{!variable}" />
                    </apex:commandLink>
```

You can use the above pattern of command link to assign the next Id and bring back the result back to page through ajax or normal getters and setters

Edit Indexing Code as per request

---

```
for(i=0;i<=acclist;i++){
   acc.indexed =i;
  lstacc.add(acc);
}
```

Prefer wrapper if you are using only for vf page

Comment: How can i assign next record ID?

Comment: index the field when queried through wrapper .

Comment: can you please post pseudo code for indexing?

Comment: @Reddy Edited to include rough example